# Filter objects with a common characteristic

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I need to find if my collection contain at least 5 elements having a common attribute value and return these elements.

I do this:

```java
cards.stream()
     .filter(card -> cards.stream()
                          .filter(card1 -> card.getSuit() == card1.getSuit()).count() >= CombinationConstant.CARD_COUNT)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Do you think it is bad practice to put another stream to filter?

Comment: I assume that the type of variable `cards` is some class or interface that extends [java.util.Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html). What is the type of each element in the `Collection`?

Comment: each element is Card type, that have private Suit field. Suit is Enum.

Comment: What is the _common variable_? Are you looking for at least five elements in `cards` that have the same `Suit`?

Comment: Yes, i need  at least five elements with same Suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not posted a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I have created one which I hope is relevant. I understand that you are trying to use the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PlayCard {
    public enum Suit {
        CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES
    }
    private Suit  suit;
    private int  value;

    public PlayCard(Suit suit, int value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<PlayCard> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        Random randomSuit = new Random();
        Suit suit = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            switch (randomSuit.nextInt(4)) {
                case 0:
                    suit = Suit.CLUBS;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    suit = Suit.DIAMONDS;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    suit = Suit.HEARTS;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    suit = Suit.SPADES;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                default:
                    suit = null;
            }
            if (suit != null) {
                cards.add(new PlayCard(suit, 0));
            }
        }
        Map<PlayCard.Suit, List<PlayCard>> map = cards.stream()
                                                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(card -> card.getSuit()));
        map.values()
           .stream()
           .filter(list -> list.size() == 5)
           .findAny()
           .ifPresentOrElse(list -> System.out.println("Found one."),
                            () -> System.out.println("Nothing found."));
    }
}
```

Some resources that may be helpful.
[Aggregate Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) lesson in Oracle's Java tutorials.
[Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams, Part 1](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html)
[Part 2: Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's efficient than your implementation. But this is one of the ways:

```
List<String> cards = List.of("a","b","aa","bb","cc");
int CARD_COUNT = 3;
    
Map<Integer, Long> counted = cards.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy((String i)-> i.length() , Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println("all counted: " + counted);
        
Map<Integer, Long> result = counted.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(k -> counted.get(k.getKey()) >= CARD_COUNT)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x1 -> x1.getValue()));;
System.out.println("filtered " + result);
```

Output:

```
all counted: {1=2, 2=3}
filtered {2=3}
```